# How do you make a KMeans prediction more accurate?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm learning about clustering and KMeans and such, so my knowldge is very basic on the topic. What I have below is a bit of a self study on how it works. Basically, if 'a' shows up in any of the columns, 'Binary' will equal 1. Essentially I am trying to teach it a pattern. I learned the following from a tutorial using the Titanic dataset, but I've adapted to my own data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

my constructed data

```
dataset = [
    [0,'x','f','g'],[1,'a','c','b'],[1,'d','k','a'],[0,'y','v','w'],
    [0,'q','w','e'],[1,'c','a','l'],[0,'t','x','j'],[1,'w','o','a'],
    [0,'z','m','n'],[1,'z','x','a'],[0,'f','g','h'],[1,'h','a','c'],
    [1,'a','r','e'],[0,'g','c','c']     
]

df = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns=['Binary','Col1','Col2','Col3'])
df.head()
```

df:

```
Binary  Col1  Col2  Col3
------------------------
  1       a    b     c
  0       x    t     v
  0       s    q     w
  1       n    m     a
  1       u    a     r
```

Encode non binary to binary:

```
labelEncoder = LabelEncoder()
labelEncoder.fit(df['Col1'])
df['Col1'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['Col1'])

labelEncoder.fit(df['Col2'])
df['Col2'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['Col2'])

labelEncoder.fit(df['Col3'])
df['Col3'] = labelEncoder.transform(df['Col3'])
```

Set clusters to two, because its either 1 or 0?

```
X = np.array(df.drop(['Binary'], 1).astype(float))
y = np.array(df['Binary'])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
kmeans.fit(X)
```

Test it:

```
correct = 0
for i in range(len(X)):
    predict_me = np.array(X[i].astype(float))
    predict_me = predict_me.reshape(-1, len(predict_me))
    prediction = kmeans.predict(predict_me)
    if prediction[0] == y[i]:
        correct += 1
```

The result:

```
print(f'{round(correct/len(X) * 100)}% Accuracy')
>>> 71%
```

How can I get it more accurate to the point where it 99.99% knows that 'a' means binary column is 1? More data?

Comment: For sure more data will help a lot.

Comment: Is that the only way? More data, or more features per row? at the moment the key is if 'a' shows up, what if I added more requirements for binary to equal 1?

Comment: I just answered my own question, so now if it equals 0, there is a 'w' somewhere in the column, and it jumped from 71% to 89%

Comment: In unsupervised problems like this, "accuracy" is ill-defined (and possibly even meaningless)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K-means does not even *try* to predict this value. Because it is an unsupervised method. Because it is not a prediction algorithm; it is a structure discovery task. Don't mistake clustering for classification.

The cluster numbers have no meaning. They are 0 and 1 because these are the first two integers. K-means is randomized. Run it a few times and you will also score just 29% sometimes.

Also, k-means is designed for *continuous* input. You can apply it on binary encoded data, but the results will be pretty poor.

Comment: How come in this tutorial https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/k-means-clustering-python they're doing exactly that for probability of survival on the titanic. Same sort of data as mine, 1 = survived, 0 = died. Is this a bad example?

Comment: Ouch. Yes, there are plenty of stupid tutorials out there that teach you bad stuff.

Comment: You do realize that the stupid classifier that always predicts 'died' is correct in 67% on this data set, so their result is worse than stupid... Not surprisingly given that y was not used in "training"...